# Requesting VAT in PayPal checkout

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart, checkout

I'm using a PayPal BuyNow button on a website.

Is there any way the user also gets to enter his European VAT-ID (if he has one) when he enters his address data on checkout ? Or do I have to create my own form, just to get the VAT-ID ?

Also, since the website is selling digital goods, I don't need a shipping address, but only a **billing** address. Is there a way to change the label on the address form the user gets from PayPal ?

Comment: You do not have sufficient options when you process through paypal button. You can achieve this things through API.